# Variável pegar a ID de um botão clicado na activity

Tags: kotlin

Olá, minha activity possui diversos botões. Eu gostaria de saber se há como uma variável coletar o botão que o usuário clicar na tela. Assim, a variável atualizaria o seu valor sempre que um botão fosse clicado.

Procurei na documentação se encontrava algo para pegar o botão e armazenar em uma variável, mas não encontrei. Logo, o meu código atual possui um listener para cada um dos botões:

```
button_0.setOnClickListener() {
.
.
.
}
button_1.setOnClickListener() {...}
button_2.setOnClickListener() {...}
button_15.setOnClickListener() {...}
```

Eu estou repetindo o mesmo código diversas vezes e isso está me causando muito trabalho para fazer manutenção sempre que encontro um novo Bug. O que eu gostaria de fazer era uma função que receberia o botão clicado e executaria o método setOnClickListener().

```
var clickedButton = getButtonClicked // Existe uma forma de armazenar o botão clicado?
buttonClicked(ClickedButton) // Executa a função genérica abaixo.

fun buttonClicked (Button) { 
   Button.setOnClickListener() {...}
```

Comment: Sua dúvida não está muito clara. O código que existe dentro dos listeners é parecido, e vc quer deixar ele meio genérico, é isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo Leonardo. O Código na verdade é basicamente o mesmo, a diferença é que cada um dos botões (1 a 15) dão valores diferentes a um grupo de variáveis. Fiz um update da questão para melhorar o entendimento.

Comment: @RamonBarros Uma opção é dentro de cada `setOnClickListener` você chamar, por exemplo, `setOnClickListener { btn -> buttonClicked(btn) }` ou passando outro valor de seu interesse

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi bem seu problema, você pode declarar no layout:

```
<Button android:text="Botao 1" onClick="buttonClicked"/>
<Button android:text="Botao 2" onClick="buttonClicked"/>
<Button android:text="Botao 3" onClick="buttonClicked"/>
```

E na activity:

```
fun buttonClicked(view: View) {
  val button = view as Button
  Log.i("Activity", " O botao com texto '" + button.text + "' foi clicado")
}
```

Comment: Cara, acho que seria isso mesmo. Eu sou estudante de programação e o que você falou faz sentido:

Mas aconteceu que apareceu o seguinte erro assim que eu criei a função e defini o onClick no button_0.

Could not find method buttonClicked(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton with id 'button_0'

Comment: Consegui. Eu já tinha uma outra função buttonClicked que não possuia (view) como parâmetro e estava conflitando. Deu certo Leonardo. Obrigado.